# Is there a way to share a certain Keeeb without directing the person to all one's public files?

Tags: privacy, sharing, keeeb

With Keeeb, is there an alternative way to share a 'keeeb' to another so you aren't giving them carte blanche to explore your entire 'keeeb'd' clips besides making all of your 'keeeb' files "private".  I have my keeeb files "public" and would ideally keep them this way but don't necessarily want to draw attention to all my files to the person I'd like to share a particular one with.

1. To do so, one would need to share a 'keeeb' without revealing my username or connection to it but is this possible?
2. Is there an alternative way if the answer to the following is no?

Comment: @Andrew Lott thanks for the Title edit. I thought of this but wasn't sure if Keeeb was very well known - especially when it did not have a tag. Not sure if you added the keeeb tag, because I thought I couldn't (or was hesitant to - my memory fails me)

Answer (score 1):

at the moment everyone can see your public Keeeb page; you are not able to show only one keeebie and not the rest of your page.